# disk I/O error when using Sqlite3 and SqlAlchemy in docker

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, docker

I have a flask app that creates a sqlite db to load fixtures for tests. When I run pytest within osx, there are no issues. However, when I set 'PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL' within a ubuntu 14.04 docker container, I get this:

```
disk I/O error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/my_app/util/sqlalchemy_helpers.py", line 23, in pragma_journalmode_wal
    cursor.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL')
OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

The sqlite db file is written to a folder within tmp that is dynamically created using python's "tempfile.mkdtemp" function. Even though the tests run as root (because docker), I still made sure the folder has full read/write/execute permissions. I verified that there is plenty of space left on /tmp. I have test code that creates, modifies, and deletes a file in the database folder, and it passes successfully.

I cannot seem to find a way to get an error code or better explanation as to what failed. Any ideas how I can better debug the issue? Could there be an issue with the docker container?

Comment: What happens if you execute anything other than `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL`? There are  whole bunch of requirements that need [to be satisfied for WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html), I suspect you may be running afoul of one.

Comment: Thanks for responding! If I remove the WAL mode (which works on OSX), then it fails on the next SQL query. It seems to simply fail on the first query of any sort. I have also tried "off" and "truncate" journal modes, they all yield the same error.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my request for clarification: what happens if there is no PRAGMA at all, but instead a SELECT FROM or INSERT? From your reply I cannot tell if SQLite is working at all. It could be claimed that using journal_mode is premature optimization; put another way, does the DB do DB things before you bring the esoterica in?

Comment: If there is no PRAGMA statement, it fails on the first query (a SELECT statement). SQLite works everywhere except in the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem right now, when recreating sqlite3 database:

1. Removed `database.sqlite3`
2. Created `database.sqlite3`
3. Setup right permissions.
4. Error ocurred.
5. After some titme figured out that I have also `database.sqlite3-shm` and `database.sqlite3-wal`
6. Removed `database.sqlite3-shm` and `database.sqlite3-wal`

And everything goes back to normal.